# remove certain parts of an api response

Tags: node.js

```
const FortniteAPI = require("fortnite-api-com");
const config = {
  apikey: "REDACTED",
  language: "en",
  debug: true
};
var Fortnite = new FortniteAPI(config);
var name = "Ninja"
Fortnite.BRStats({name: name, accountType: "epic", timeWindow:"lifetime", image: "none"})
.then(res => {
  console.log(res);
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

I don't even know how to word what I need help with hopefully I made sense with my words Lol!
If anyone could help me it would be appreciated!

[How do I remove the parts that are crossed out?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QbnQ.jpg)

Comment: We're not your personal code-writing or research service. What have you tried to meet this requirement? Where are you getting stuck? Share your code as a [mre] along with a specific explanation of where you're running into roadblocks in completing this. See [ask].

Comment: @esqew please read the question before voting down ;)

Comment: @sina.ce Not sure how you established that (a) I haven't read the question (considering it *is* a thinly-veiled request for us to do the actual legwork for the OP), or (b) that I've voted down (considering votes are anonymous by design).

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`lodash` => `omit` function](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#omit):

```
var object = { 'a': 1, 'b': '2', 'c': 3 };
 
_.omit(object, ['a', 'c']);
// => { 'b': '2' }
```